# Querying MySQL SHOW GRANTS in bash script includes local files

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I am trying to write a bash script to check if a particular MySQL user has the appropriate privileges before continuing.

If I execute the command directly from mysql, I get the following:

```
$ mysql -u db_user -pmypassword
mysql> show grants;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for db_user@localhost                                                                                            |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'db_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'some-password-here' |
```

That gives me exactly what I am looking for.

The weird behavior comes into play when I put it into a script. I wrote this very basic script to illustrate:

```
passwd=mypassword
user=db_user

line=`mysql -u ${user} -p${passwd}  -e "show grants for '${user}'@'localhost';"`
echo $line
```

I get the following:

```
Grants for db_user@localhost GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON blah.tst dropsite.sh mysql.sh runasroot.sh testopts.sh TO 'db_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'some-password-here'
```

Somehow, the files in the local directory also got listed.  They are

```
blah.tst     <----- This test file was added when I discovered the behavior 
dropsite.sh 
mysql.sh 
runasroot.sh 
testopts.sh
```

I can't seem to figure out why these are coming up. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote your variable:

```
echo "$line"
```

When you don't quote the variable, wildcards in the value get expanded, so `*.*` in the result is replaced with all the files matching that pattern.

Comment: OMG.  That did it.  I swear...variables in bash drive me nuts.  Thanks for the quick reply.